# Finding Active Project from Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Quick question.

I am working on an eclipse plugin project, and want to create and store files in a folder called "Levels".

How do I find the "active project" when the user runs my plugin?

In other words, How do I find out what project is the plugin being run for?

Comment: What does "runs my plug-in" actually mean? Creating or opening a file? Invoking a Command? The runtime context matters.

Comment: the plugin opens a GUI, that helps the user create files in their project. So i need to find a way to know for what project the plugin is being run for, so the file can be generated in their project.

Comment: You know how this System.getProperty("user.dir") gets the project name, is there a way to cal this with the project that is open when the plugin is started.

Comment: There is no such thing as the 'active project' in Eclipse. You can do things like find the project containing the currently selected object (if there is one). Note the `System.getProperty("user.dir") ` has nothing whatsoever to do with Eclipse projects. Are you using something like the 'New' wizard to open your code?